# i am not able to launch the web browser using TestNG

Tags: selenium, testng

below is the code : im not able launch the browser using the code . please suggest the solution

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class NewTest {
public WebDriver driver;`enter code here`
  @Test
  public void VerifyHomepageTitle() {
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.navigate().to("http://google.com");
  driver.quit();
            }
      }
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? What's the problem? What's the error?

Comment: r u running this as Run as testng

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the web page immediately after opening using 'driver.quit()'. Comment this code and try you will see the difference.